# Android: Adding database to apk

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio, apk

OK so here's the deal. I'm developing apk and I'd like to add database (atm at .txt) so my question is:

How should I add it to my apk, just load it all to table or there is any better way to do it?

And after that I'd like to click on button and be able to start writing item from base and phone would help out. For example I've got in database chicken breast, chicken leggs, eggs 
and when I write "br" my apk shows most accurate position.

ps. my database got about 3k positions.

Comment: 3k rows and `atm at .txt`? C'mon. This even remotely makes no sense. Spend some time with tutorials on Android sqlite first and come back with exact question

Comment: Please explain what is atm at .txt. Also show us what you have done and which parts are you having trouble with, so we can better help you

Comment: i've got it all as text document, I don't want full solution here I just want to know what should I use in android + database. 
Putting it simply to table or trying something new. 

Ok I've found answer I need : sqlite db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access a file when creating an app you can place it in the assets folder inside of your project. You could then call  Context.getAssets().open("FILENAME") to access it as an input stream. 
You might want to consider a sqlitedb instead of a text file,The following tutorial can assist you in setting up an android project using a sqlite db. 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Thanks for info sqlite db that's what i was looking for! Huge thanks mate :). I'm not here for full solution to my problem I tried to get just hint what to use in this situation. Thanks again mate ;)